# How to append an XMLDocument into LocalStorage without deleting the older one

Tags: javascript, html, xml, parsing, dom

I'm currently having an issue on this:
I have a js code which creates an XML Document, a simple one. The problem is that when i rerun the function that creats the document, it replaces the older one for the newer.

I would like something like this:

```
<root>
     <person>
            <name>Jon</name>
            <age>18</age>

     </person>
     <person>
            <name>Paco</name>
            <age>76</age>

     </person>
     <person>
            <name>Marta</name>
            <age>42</age>

     </person>


</root>
```

But I can only get to work one document at a time, I can't "append, or push" the newly created xml documents into the first one. Local Storage always stores the newest.
My JS Code

The userInputs are from a form tag

```
function addTodo(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const userInputHTMLCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("userAdd");
  console.log(userInputHTMLCollection);

  // EDITOR: added missing '=' below:
  const userInput = [].map.call(
    userInputHTMLCollection,
    (element) => element.value
  );
  console.log(userInput[0]);
  console.log(userInput[1]);
  console.log(userInput[2]);
  console.log(userInput[3]);

  //Creem la plantilla XML.

  txt1 = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`;

  txt2 = `<filmoteca>`;
  txt3 = `<peli>`;
  txt4 = `<titol>` + userInput[0] + `</titol>`;
  txt5 = `<genere>` + userInput[1] + `</genere>`;
  txt6 = `<director>` + userInput[2] + `</director>`;
  txt7 = `<any>` + userInput[3] + `</any>`;
  txt8 = `</peli>`;
  txt9 = `</filmoteca>`;
  txt = txt1 + txt2 + txt3 + txt4 + txt5 + txt6 + txt7 + txt8 + txt9;
  console.log("Text Principal" + txt);

  parser = new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt, "text/xml");
  localStorage.setItem("data", xmlDoc);
  console.log(xmlDoc);

  var xmlString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlDoc);
  console.log(xmlString);

  // ...
}
```

The function below will create an XMLDocument into the LocalStorage, but I want to keep adding more.

Here's the code which tries to append or push the new xml into the older one

```
function afegirLS() {
  const userInputHTMLCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("userAdd");

  const userInput = [].map.call(
    userInputHTMLCollection,
    (element) => element.value
  );

  var informacio = localStorage.getItem("data");

  txt2 = `<filmoteca>`;
  txt3 = `<peli>`;
  txt4 = `<titol>` + userInput[0] + `</titol>`;
  txt5 = `<genere>` + userInput[1] + `</genere>`;
  txt6 = `<director>` + userInput[2] + `</director>`;
  txt7 = `<any>` + userInput[3] + `</any>`;
  txt8 = `</peli>`;
  txt9 = `</filmoteca>`;
  txt_nou = txt1 + txt2 + txt3 + txt4 + txt5 + txt6 + txt7 + txt8 + txt9;
  console.log("Text Nou" + txt_nou);

  parser2 = new DOMParser();
  afegirXML = parser2.parseFromString(txt_nou, "text/xml");

  console.log(afegirXML);
  //var xmlString2 = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(string_vell);
  //console.log(xmlString2);

  //txt_nou.push(xmlString);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to store multiple XML docs into localStorage, but you are only storing a single doc.

```js
function addTodo(e) {
  // ...
  xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt, "text/xml");
  localStorage.setItem("data", xmlDoc);
  // ...
}
```

If you want to store multiple docs, you can store and retrieve an array.

```js
let xmlDocs = [];
/ ...
function addTodo(e) {
  let xmlDocs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data')) || [];
  // ...
  xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt, "text/xml");
  xmlDocs.push(xmlDoc);
  localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(xmlDocs));
  // ...
}
```

Note the use of `JSON.stringify()` to convert the array to a string, and `JSON.parse()` to convert the string back to an array. This guarantees that `localStorage` stores only strings (as required).

Comment: Hi @terrymorse that's a good idea, but do I need to use JSON.stringify? I would like to only do this with XML, or JS not JSON. Cause i'm working on a full-oriented xml website. Many thanks for your time and patience!

Comment: @Learner33 If you are trying to store data that isn't a string to `localStorage`, then you must first convert the data to a string beforehand. A general way to do this is with `JSON.stringify`. If your data is a DOM tree, you can alternatively use the XML [serializeToString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer) method.

Comment: Thanks! So it will be all the same but using th XMLSerializer.serializeToString() instead of JSON.stringify().

Comment: @Learner33 Yes, but `serializeToString()` only works if your data is  the root of a DOM tree or subtree. It fails for other data, like JavaScript arrays.

Comment: Okay... @terrymorse because I'm working only with XML, not JSON Objects. Its just a simple project to know how to work with XML data. Thanks again! I'll try the code cause this was turning me crazy hehe!